# Install Pre-Generated Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to intercept the helm YAML and customize it using a Python script, and then install it. I have been doing something like `helm template | python3 script... | kubectl apply -f -` but of course this doesn't create a helm release in my cluster, so I lose out on `helm rollback` etc.

I have considered using Kustomize but it doesn't have the features that I'd like.

Is there a way to take pre-generated YAML, like that from `helm template` or `helm install --dry-run` and then install/upgrade that **using** helm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what post-renderers are for?

See https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering

> A post-renderer can be any executable that accepts rendered Kubernetes manifests on STDIN and returns valid Kubernetes manifests on STDOUT. It should return an non-0 exit code in the event of a failure. This is the only "API" between the two components. It allows for great flexibility in what you can do with your post-render process.
>
> A post renderer can be used with install, upgrade, and template. To use a post-renderer, use the --post-renderer flag with a path to the renderer executable you wish to use:
>
> `$ helm install mychart stable/wordpress --post-renderer ./path/to/executable`

I haven't used it myself yet, but it looks interesting if you want to run your own alternative kustomize.

See https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/carvel-ytt/tree/develop/examples/helm-ytt-post-renderer for an example that is not kustomize.

Comment: I haven't run to confirm this but the STDIN/STDIN executable sounds right, marking as correct.